# How To Implement Alerts Using Node.js And Express

Tags: node.js, express

The Problem I'am having is trying to find a way to successfully implement the ability to have alerts pop up on my Node.js web application.

I have tried to implement libraries such as "Flash" and different variations of flash e.g. "connect-flash", "express-flash" but non of which have seemed to work.

The alert should pop up once an api request has been sent successfully

I'm using these technologies...

Express, Passport, Session, Router etc...

Hopefully the community will be able to provide a suitable solution/example to my issue

Link to project code....
https://github.com/EthanMcCracken/GradedUnitProject

Many Thanks
Ethan

Comment: Hmm.  On the surface, it doesn't seem like this would require any work on the backend (within your Nodejs application on the server).  It could help if you included some snippets of what you've tried, how it ended up working, and what you expected to happen.

Comment: I've tried various technologies like flash & express-messages etc but just can't get them to work I think I may be implementing them wrong I was wondering if anyone had an example or solution they could provide of the easiest way to display alerts...

Comment: May be it could help to explain a little more about what you're hoping to accomplish. Normally if the frontend is making a request to the backend, the frontend would have all of the information required to display and alert when that backend request is completed.

Comment: I would a like to have an alert pop up after an a request  has been send to the api successfully I have updated my question with a link to my github

Comment: The link returns a 404 error.  If it works for you, your repo may be private.  And it sounds like what you desire is more related to the frontend than the backend.

Comment: Sorry about that , thats it been set to public

Comment: So, where is the API call being made?  And what UI action is triggering the API call?

Comment: The API call is being made in the routes.js file in the "home post route" roughly 44 lines down

Comment: Cool. And what in the UI makes a call to this route?

Comment: The user enters in their email in a text input and hits the submit button which sends the API request and I want a success message to appear in the form of an alert but have tried to implement the message and it has not worked.

Comment: So, where is this form located in your view?

Comment: The form is located in the views folder and is in the file index.ejs at the top in "Masthead"

Comment: Your best bet would be to invoke some Javascript to make a  POST request to your backend via AJAX.  This would allow you to interpret responses from your backend with a different status code than 200 as errors, and display a warning to the user.

Comment: Thanks!!!, are you able to help with providing any information or documentation on how to do this ?

Comment: I recommend looking up information on XMLHTTPRequest.  A good starting point is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) but there are definitely a lot of resources on this that are a Google away.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate all your help!!! 